# Setting up Ubuntu vm and forgot to add a search domain

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name, ipv4

I was setting up an Ubuntu DNS server VM and accidentally forgot to add a search domain. How can I add this to my system? I set a static IP and had DHCP turned off on the machine. I am also using NetworkManager, would I add this configuration to my Netplan Yaml file?
[image: Ipv4 configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an working example from my Ubuntu 22.04 server.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:  [10.0.0.100/24]
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
         search: [mydomain.intern]
         addresses: [10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3]
```

You need to add `nameservers:` and `search:` to your yaml file below the network interface.